# treeFor which $n,m$ is $K_{n,m}$ a tree?

Tags: graph-theory

How can I formally prove for which $n,m$ is $K_{n,m}$ a tree? I feel like it only works when $n=m=1$, but I have trouble with writing it down formally.

*Edit:* A tree is a connected graph with no cycles and $K_{n,m}$ is a complete

Comment: Well, there are more cases than $n=m=1$. But the way you'd prove something is not a tree is by demonstrating a cycle. Demonstrating that something is a tree might technically seem harder - there are no cycles. But, in this case, it's pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ and $m$ are each at least $2$, then there will be a cycle.

Do you see why?

You remark that if $n = m = 1$, then $K_{n,m}$ is a tree.

What if one of $n$ or $m$ is $1$, but the other is a greater positive integer?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $K_{m,n}$ is always connected and

$$m+n=mn+1 \Leftrightarrow mn-m-n+1=0 \Leftrightarrow (m-1)(n-1)=0$$